# Center Gravity for TextView doesn't work on xxhdpi in RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android

I have TextViews with square background with numbers that appear every second. I use a square image for background and set the text gravity center to center the numbers in the squares. It doesn't work on xxhdpi phones. How I can center the numbers?

[image]

This is the code:

```
displayingCell = new TextView(MyActivity.this);
displayingCell.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
displayingCell.setTextSize(mySize);
displayingCell.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
displayingCell.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
displayingLayoutParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(diameter, diameter);
displayingLayoutParam.setMargins(marginLeft, marginTop, 0, 0);
displayingCell.setLayoutParams(displayingLayoutParam);
displayingCell.setBackground(myImage);
displayingCell.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
```

Comment: Could you post you layout xml?

Comment: I add cells programmatically.

Comment: You shouldn't have to use add margins if you are using Gravity center, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: So how it works on other devices?

Comment: A good tip to when you are building layouts and views by code is to do it first in XML and see the changes with your eyes direcelty and then remulate it with code with the same properties used in XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove

```
displayingLayoutParam.setMargins
```

and add

```
displayingLayoutParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
```

Comment: Still no changes.

Comment: What are those "diameter"? Maybe you should change both to "ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT"

Answer (score 0):

if this problem only appear on xxhdpi device.. than you can check it runtime for device and set `marginbottom` to text like this. i am adding margin to my toolbar text. hope you will get this trick

```
switch (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi) {
            case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
                Log.d("density:", "high");
                toolbar.setTitleMarginStart(160);
                break;
            case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
                // ...
                Log.d("density:", "xhigh");
                toolbar.setTitleMarginStart(200);
                break;
            case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
                Log.d("density:", "xxhigh");
                toolbar.setTitleMarginStart(380);
                break;
        }
```

Comment: I set a bottom padding for text but it shows like this:
http://i.imgur.com/aXID4ig.png

Comment: remove padding to text and try to set margin top for image view.

Comment: and also try to understand difference between padding and margin.. margin is for outer space and padding is for inner space.. like we giving in css.